# How to compile one typescript file in a larger project to a different file extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES3",
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "strict": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["d.ts"],
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "include": ["*.ts"]
}
```

My project has a number of .ts files and a file of types in `d.ts/index.d.ts`.

I want to compile just one, JUST ONE, of the .ts files in my project and output it to a file with an `.rr` extension.

`--outFile` works but I can't figure out what the CLI is supposed to be told such that all the settings in the `tsconfig.json` apply. Currently I get a screenful of errors about `TS2304: Cannot find name 'blah'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outFile` is working with below configurations. `outFile` can be used with `amd` or `system` module only. I tried your config where facing issues for `lib`. If I remove it, everything works as expected.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "outFile": "./output/test.rr",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./testfile.ts"
    ]
}
```

Your configuration after making changes, module and removing lib and types,

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "outFile": "./output/testfile11.rr",
        "target": "ES3",
        "strict": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "system",
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "include": [
        "testfile.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I'm curious to know: what about the types/classes/interfaces that I have already "declare"d in index.d.ts? Are these consulted during compilation?

Comment: thanks and types inside compiler options takes sub folder but here you can provide the directory names instead of "d.ts". I moved index.d.ts into types folder and added "types": [
            "./types"
        ], into tsconfig. It worked.